# bitmap.getpixel(x,y) return value is not equal for same image in different devices

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to find rectangular colored region based on color code. Using `bitmap.getpixel(x,y)` to find the current coordinate color value. For some `x,y` in same image in different devices giving different value.

Comment: Where do you get your bitmap from?  If you are reading from a file type such as jpeg or png, it could be that different versions of android decode them in a slightly different way, giving you a slightly different bitmap.

Comment: i am getting it from my server as jpeg file. so  will it affect each pixels in a image

Comment: Are you using Volley to download the image? You should know that Volley will automatically downscale images according to the device's screen dimensions in pixels (size*density) which varies dramatically over different devices.

Comment: yeah .. i am using volley.. but i didn't load it to the image view and all.. getting the bitmap from volley image loader then i am accessing  each pixel values by getpixel(x,y)..

Comment: Yep, thats your problem. If you scale the bitmap, you will not get the pixels you want. There should be some way to turn off scaling in Volley.

Comment: @JonasCz but i did not associate the bitmap with any image view and i didn't scale it..

Comment: It could be possible that Volley scales the image automatically, even if you don't associate it with an ImageView. Check the width x height of bitmap on  your different devices, and see if they are the same.